# Default website image for social sharing - Issue

Tags: web, thumbnails

to get this done I found the below code on other post.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/logo.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1024">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="1024">
```

This works fine if I use **http://example.com**. But when I use **www.mysite.com** this is fetching another thumbnail.

Can anyone help me to get the same image when I access with **www** and without **www** as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just took time. No issues with the code.